# Permission issue while starting a service from android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-permissions

I have written a service as part of an application. I try to call this service from a second application using the following code:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent () ;
    intent.setClassName("com.test" ,"com.test.DownloadService") ;
    // Create a new Messenger for the communication back
    Messenger messenger = new Messenger(handler);
    intent.putExtra("MESSENGER", messenger);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.vogella.com/index.html"));
    intent.putExtra("urlpath", "http://www.vogella.com/index.html");
    this.startService(intent);
```

It gives the following exception

```
07-10 09:27:28.819: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4226): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.inject/com.inject.MyActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent { dat=http://www.vogella.com/index.html cmp=com.test/.DownloadService (has extras) } without permission not exported from uid 10109
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1971)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1996)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:126)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1156)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4458)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent { dat=http://www.vogella.com/index.html cmp=com.test/.DownloadService (has extras) } without permission not exported from uid 10109
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1122)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:359)
    at com.inject.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:28)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1935)
    ... 11 more
```

Why this permission issue occurs?

The following code works perfect when I call the service from the same app:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DownloadService.class);
    // Create a new Messenger for the communication back
    Messenger messenger = new Messenger(handler);
    intent.putExtra("MESSENGER", messenger);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.vogella.com/index.html"));
    intent.putExtra("urlpath", "http://www.vogella.com/index.html");
    startService(intent);
```

Can someone please let me know why I get this permission issue when I call the service from a different application, though I have given all the required permissions in App2's manifest.

**EDIT**

Manifest of App2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.inject"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
    <activity android:name="MyActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Manifest of App1 which contains the service

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.test"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name="DownloadService" >
    </service>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: it seems like something is missing in your manifests. add the manifests of both your apps.

Comment: Your both application's uID is different..

Answer (score 17):

The service isn't available to other applications because you haven't made it explicitly available. Your service needs to be defined like this:

```
<service android:name="DownloadService"
         android:exported="true">
</service>
```

You don't need any extra permissions (unless you want to use them)

Answer (score 2):

Have your read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#Permissions)? It is quite clear with this issue:

> Global access to a service can be enforced when it is declared in its
>   manifest's  tag. By doing so, other applications will need to
>   declare a corresponding  element in their own
>   manifest to be able to start, stop, or bind to the service.
>
> As of GINGERBREAD, when using Context.startService(Intent), you can
>   also set Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION and/or
>   Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION on the Intent. This will grant
>   the Service temporary access to the specific URIs in the Intent.
>   Access will remain until the Service has called stopSelf(int) for that
>   start command or a later one, or until the Service has been completely
>   stopped. This works for granting access to the other apps that have
>   not requested the permission protecting the Service, or even when the
>   Service is not exported at all.
>
> In addition, a service can protect individual IPC calls into it with
>   permissions, by calling the checkCallingPermission(String) method
>   before executing the implementation of that call.
>
> See the Security and Permissions document for more information on
>   permissions and security in general.

Show us your `AndroidManifest.xml` if you still have permission problems after reading the documentation. Also see the [`exported` and the `permission`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html) attribute of the service in your manifest.

Comment: I tried adding `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);`, still it does not resolve the issue and gives the same exception